# Smarty loop count

Tags: php, smarty

I am new to smarty concepts. I have used section loop in my tpl page to show the user data, in this page i need the section count.

For example:

```
{section name=i loop=$getFriends start=0 step=1}

{/section}
```

I need to check the  section count for the array values($getFriends) to display some messages for the users. so please guide me on how to make the section count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the total count use [{$smarty.section.customer.total}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl#section.property.total)

Comment: i have got this same idea from smarty.net.Thank you

Comment: Same can be done for a `foreach` loop with `$smart.foreach.customer.total`

Answer (score 2):

By 'count' do you mean the current index of the loop?

If so you can use this

```
{section name=customer loop=$custid}
  {$smarty.section.customer.index} id: {$custid[customer]}<br />
{/section}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl#section.property.index

Answer (score 1):

Try {counter} http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.counter.tpl
Exapmle:

```
{counter start=0 print=false name=bla}
{section name=i loop=$getFriends start=0 step=1}
   {counter}
{/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var=val value=0}
{section name=i loop=$data}
         {assign var=val value=$val+1}
{/section}
```